# Derivative of equation in matrix form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need to compute first derivatives of the following function $S(w)$ with respect to $w$. Then solve it. The reason behind that is to minimize $S(w)$.

$S(w)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i^{1/2} \bigg(y_i - \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_j y_j\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_j y_j  (1-\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_j y_j) \bigg)^{-1/2} E_i + \lambda (\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_j-1)$

where $w^{1/2}$ is a square root of vector $w$, $w$ is a vector $n\times 1$, and $y$ is a vector $n\times 1$. Note that $i =j $, $E_i$ is constant

$\frac{\partial S(w)}{\partial w} = ?$

Comment: you are talking abour an $X$ but I don't see any in $S(w)$. And what is $w^{1/2}$ for you ? And $E_i $?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: If $w^{1/2}$ is a vector, then it doesn't have any sense, you are adding vectors and scalars

Comment: This is the same question in matrix form, maybe more clear. $S(w) = (y-e)^T W X (X^T W N W^T X)^{-1} X^T W  (y-e)$, where $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix, $W$ is a diagonal matrix $n \times n$, $D = e(1-e)$, where $e = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_i y_i$

Comment: Sorry i mean $N= e(1-e)$, So $D=N$

Comment: ok we can consider $e$ as a vector $n \times 1$ . Or if we can consider it as $e= yw$ matrix $n \times n$. you can see the correct way. Because we can adjust the $e$.

Comment: $y$ is $n \times 1$ and $w$ is $n \times 1$. Seems to me that $e$ is more $y^Tw$